# Filter data dynamically based on a hierarchical user id in cube.js

Tags: postgresql, cube.js

I have two tables called Writers and Publications where there is a foreign key `publications.writer_id = writers.id`

### Writers

| id (int) | parent_id (int) | role (varchar) | name (varchar) | path (ltree) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | ADMIN | Firstname Lastname |  |
| 2 | 1 | EDITOR | Anon Anon | 1.2 |
| 3 | 2 | WEB EDITOR | Maisy Tickles | 1.2.3 |
| 4 | 2 | WEB EDITOR | Jack Beanstalk | 1.2.4 |
| 5 | 3 | WEB PROOFREADER | Sunny Ray | 1.2.3.5 |

### Publications

| id (int) | writer_id (FK) | publication_name (varchar) | word_length (int) | published (datetime) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | My First Magazine | 6000 | 2019-09-09 09:00:00 |
| 2 | 2 | My Second Magazine | 6000 | 2019-09-16 09:00:00 |
| 3 | 3 | My First Article | 1000 | 2019-09-23 09:00:00 |
| 4 | 4 | My First Article | 1500 | 2019-09-23 09:00:00 |
| 5 | 4 | My Second Article | 600 | 2019-10-01 09:00:00 |
| 6 | 5 | My First Piece | 600 | 2020-10-01 09:00:00 |

I want to do a proof of concept in `cube.js` Developer Playground to show various charts. Is it possible to filter dynamically based on the user_id so that they can only access content that is equal to or in their subtree i.e.

- If an ADMIN/EDITOR is using, they can see all the publications
- If the WEB EDITOR (`writers.id=4`) is using the application, they can only see their own articles (`publications.id in (4,5)`)
- If the WEB EDITOR (`writers.id=3`) is using the application, they can see their publication and the WEB PROOFREADER's one (`publications.id in (3,6)`)
- The WEB PROOFREADER should only see their publication (`publications.id=6`)

These are the models I have set up so far

```
cube(`Writers`, {
  sql: `SELECT * FROM public.writers`,
  
  preAggregations: {},
  
  joins: {

    Publications:{
      sql: `${CUBE}.id = ${Publication}.writer_id`,
      relationship: `hasMany`
    }
    
  },
  
  measures: {
    count: {
      type: `count`,
      drillMembers: [id, name, created]
    }
  },
  
  dimensions: {
    id: {
      sql: `id`,
      type: `number`,
      primaryKey: true
    },

 role: {
          sql: `role`,
          type: `string`,
        },
};





cube(`Publications`, {
  sql: `SELECT * FROM public.publications`,
  
  preAggregations: {},
  
  joins: {

    Writer:{
      sql: `${CUBE}.writer_id = ${Writers}.id`,
      relationship: `hasOne`
    }
    
  },
  
  measures: {
    count: {
      type: `count`,
      drillMembers: [id, name, created]
    }
  },

 dimensions: {
     id: {
          sql: `id`,
          type: `number`,
          primaryKey: true
        },

     wordLength: {
              sql: `word_length`,
              type: `number`,
            },
};
```

I know there are `filters` and `segments` but these appear to be static. Is there any way to pass a writer_id to filter the relevant data dynamically? (I have no previous knowledge of JS)

Answer (score 1):

I think these recipes can help you:

- https://cube.dev/docs/recipes/role-based-access
- https://cube.dev/docs/recipes/column-based-access
- https://cube.dev/docs/recipes/passing-dynamic-parameters-in-a-query

Answer (score 0):

I think you can query the cube from your front-end application with a filter of id.